# When t run my code with @test annotation, my code returns following error message

Tags: testng

```
[RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 7.0.1
```

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   com/google/inject/Stage

Comment: Hi @Bindu Gowda did you solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

There is an open issue that is tracking this discrepancy.

See here: https://github.com/cbeust/testng/issues/2223

As an alternate, what you can consider doing is, to switch over to using IntelliJ because this problem is perhaps specific to the eclipse testng plugin.